# Is there a better/less verbose way to declare this repeated WPF Binding?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

This is not a huge deal, but I'd like to learn more about WPF and I am wondering if there is a less-verbose way to handle the following problem. I have XAML code set up (snippet below) to show and hide columns in a data grid based on the Boolean property `ShowAdvancedContent` of source object `wndState`. The data grid itself is bound to a data source, not to object wndState, so I am specifying the Source attribute and since I am converting from bool to Visibility, I am specifying the Converter attribute.

```
<locset:WindowState x:Key="wndState" />
<locdata:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToCollapsedConverter"
                                      True="Visible"  False="Collapsed" />

...

<DataGridHyperlinkColumn x:Name="urlColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Url}"
            Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=urlColHdr}"
            MinWidth="100" Width="*"
            Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource wndState}, Path=ShowAdvancedContent, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=BoolToCollapsedConverter}, Mode=OneWay}">
    <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="OnHyperlinkClick" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridHyperlinkColumn>

<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="addressColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Address}"
        Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=addressColHdr}"
        MinWidth="120" Width="SizeToCells"
        Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource wndState}, Path=ShowAdvancedContent, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=BoolToCollapsedConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />

<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="portColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Port}"
        Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=portColHdr}"
        MinWidth="80" Width="SizeToCells"
        Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource wndState}, Path=ShowAdvancedContent, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=BoolToCollapsedConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />

<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="protocolVersionColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=ProtocolVersion}"
        Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=protocolColHdr}"
        Width="SizeToHeader"
        Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource wndState}, Path=ShowAdvancedContent, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=BoolToCollapsedConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

This approach works just fine -- as I toggle the value of ShowAdvancedContent, the columns collapse and become visible. However, I am repeating this exact string four times:

```
Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource wndState},
                     Path=ShowAdvancedContent,
                     Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=BoolToCollapsedConverter},
                     Mode=OneWay}" />
```

So today when I changed the name of the property from "AdvancedColVisibility" to "ShowAdvancedContent" I had to change it in four places. (Like I wrote above, not a huge deal. I'm asking more for the sake of learning about WPF than about managing this specific block of code.)

Is there a way to declare that binding one time and reference that declaration on each of the four columns, for example as a binding resource of some type or via a Syle resource?

Answer (score 0):

Create a style and apply it to your columns.

Somewhere in your resources, create the style:

```
<Style
    x:Key="AdvancedColumn"
    TargetType="DataGridColumn">
    <Setter
        Property="Visibility"
        Value="{Binding ShowAdvancedContent,
                        Source={StaticResource wndState},
                        Converter={StaticResource BoolToCollapsedConverter},
                        Mode=OneWay}" />
</Style>
```

Then apply it to your columns:

```
<DataGridTextColumn
    x:Name="addressColumn"
    Binding="{Binding Path=Address}"
    Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=addressColHdr}"
    MinWidth="120"
    Width="SizeToCells"
    Style="{StaticResource AdvancedColumn}"/>
```

Note, this is *WPF-like pseudoxaml* and is not tested.

Comment: This is the _sort_ of approach I was hoping for, but DataGridColumn and its descendants do not have a Style property. (DataGridColumn does not inherit from either FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement).

Comment: @dgvid: Yowch... What about changing the target type to DataGridCell, setting the style using DataGridColumn.CellStyle, and setting the *cell's* Width to 0?  You'd have to do the HeaderStyle as well.  A bit of a hack, but it might work...

Comment: @dgvid: It *is* a DependencyObject, so you might be able to create a Silverlight "Behavior" that, in response to bindings, collapses the column.  I consider that also somewhat of a hack, as this requires an attached property, and those are static.  You'd have to wrap all your references up in an instance that manages them as weak references.